# Write a function which finds a substring in a string and replaces all such occurrences with another string?

Tags: algorithm, string, substring

Write a function which finds a substring in a string and replaces all such occurrences with another string. Prototype of the function :

```
      char* FindReplace(char* src, char* find, char* replace);
```

**Test case 1:**

INPUT:
SRC[] = **"SIVASAI".**
find[] = **"AS"**
Replace[] = **"ASAS"**

OUTPUT:
SRC[] = **"SIVASASAI"**

**Test case 2:**
SRC[] = **"SIVASAI".**
find[] = **"VASA"**
Replace[] = **"A"**

OUTPUT:
SRC[] = **"SIAI"**

**Solution should be Time Efficient .**

Comment: what's the output for the test case FindReplace("AAA", "AA", "AB")?

Comment: smells strongly of homework

Comment: Voting to close, not a question, more of an instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:
1) Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm
2) Boyer-Moore algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm
3) Rabin-Karp algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm

Comment: These  algorithms good but we cannot write code for these approaches in Interview because of time constraint